# Node.js adding and subtracting not working

Tags: node.js

So, my code is this:

```
money - args[0];
bankmoney + args[0];
```

But the problem is, that the - and the + are not working (It's not subtracting or adding the args(so the message which was written). But -- and ++ or -= and += are still working. Please help me out.
Thanks!

Comment: yeah but the problem is in the bankmoney he says (if i add 2 to the bank) 02 and not 2

Comment: the code is: let bankmoney = 0 (visual studio code)

Comment: `money - args[0]` does not modify `money`. You might like to read more about [expressions and operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators) or the Operators section of this [beginner tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/A_first_splash).

Answer (score 1):

They are working but the result is then stored nowhere. It lacks an [assignment operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_(computer_science)) (basically a `=`).
The operators `++` and `+=` imply it.